# Minimum times needed to toss a coin for a certain probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Trying to solve this question:

How many times should be flip an unbiased coin so that the probability of getting at least one head is 98%?

I know the final answer is 6, but I'm trying to figure out how to get there.

The only thing I've tried is 0.98 = (1/2) (1/2) ^ (n-1) and solving for n, but that wasn't right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probability of getting AT LEAST one head= 1-Probability of getting no head = 1-Probability of getting all tails.

In n tries, the probability of getting all tails is
\begin{equation*}
\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n}
\end{equation*}
Can you use this information to finish it off?

Comment: Ah, I think I got it! I solved for 0.98 = 1 - (1/2)^n and got 5.6. Rounding that up gives me the final answer of 6. Thank you so much :)